# dplyr filter values of a dataframe variable using ifelse?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataframe:

```
structure(list(a = c(1, 2, 3), b = c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)), .Names = c("a", 
"b"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

and a function:

```
foo <- function(df, L = TRUE) {

    return(df %>% filter(ifelse(L, b, !b))) }
```

When I run it, it seems that ifelse doesn't do the job.
Please advise how can I "tell" the function to filter for all TRUE's if L is TRUE and FALSE's otherwise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ifelse` needs a vectorize argument when used with `dplyr::filter` or `dplyr::mutate`. That means the `condition` should be a vector of length matching with row numbers provided to `ifelse` as `condition` is evaluated for each row.

You can modify your function to provide `L` as below:

```
library(dplyr)

foo <- function(df, L = TRUE) {
  # replicate the condition to match number of rows
  return(df %>% filter(ifelse(rep(L,nrow(.)), b, !b))) 
  }
```

Now verify results:

```
foo(df)
# # A tibble: 2 x 2
# a b    
# <dbl> <lgl>
# 1  1.00 T    
# 2  2.00 T    

foo(df,FALSE)
# # A tibble: 1 x 2
# a b    
# <dbl> <lgl>
# 1  3.00 F
```

Comment: Thank you so so much! Solved my issue and I have understood the issue!

Answer (score 1):

What about this in base R?

```
foo <- function(df, L = TRUE) {
  if (L == TRUE) return(df[df$b == TRUE, ])
  else return(df[df$b == FALSE, ])
}
```

***Yielding***

```
> foo(df, L=TRUE)
# A tibble: 2 x 2
      a b    
  <dbl> <lgl>
1     1 TRUE 
2     2 TRUE 
> foo(df, L=FALSE)
# A tibble: 1 x 2
      a b    
  <dbl> <lgl>
1     3 FALSE
```